# Adding arrays to Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a pages array containing objects. Each object contains an array of items called blocks. I'm getting an error message when I try to add it, what's the best way to get around this?

```
     let projectId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
     let docTitle = this.projectTitle.title;

     this.pages.forEach((page) => {
       let pageT = page.pageTitle;
       let pageD = page.pageDesc;
       let id = page.id;
       let blocks = page.blocks;
       db.collection(docTitle + projectId).doc(pageT).set({
           page: {pageTitle:pageT, pageDesc: pageD, blocks:blocks, id:id }
         })
         .then(function() {
           console.log("Document successfully written!");
         })
         .catch(function(error) {
           console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
         });
     })
```

Here's the error: 
[image]

Comment: "'m get an error message" What's the exact error message, and what line raises that error message?

Comment: I've added a screen shot to my question

Comment: Don't add screenshots of textual contents please. Just add the actual text to the question, so that it can be searched for, copy/pasted, etc.

Comment: The screen shot gave more info